# Where is the good php validation library like jquery validation

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

I used [jquery validation](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation) for front-end data validate. But i need to do validate on sever-side as well.

I'm looking for a good validation library in php which has the features as many as jquery validation, including required field, check email, check number, min-length, max-length, equalto another field and custom validate method.

I'm using codeigniter and i found that it has a form_validate library, it has most of the features in jquery validation but it can not be used without codeigniter and its erroer report is a html snippet not an array structure. I also want to use it in a restful service.

So if there is another library which can do the job like jquery validation i will use that one or i may need to do some work to modify the codeigniter form validation myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might want to look at some frameworks.  Feature like more OOP styled Forms / CRUD.  I often use these for form validation: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.html

Comment: PHP now has built in validators, you should take a look at them http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php However, they probably don't cover everything you need.

Comment: Had to reread your question. Think I missed main point. I've never found something out of the box that ties the server/client side validation just the way I want. I've taken the Zend Form validation and used it though in the way you describe, passing back post of full form, getting back JSON listing failures.

Comment: Thanks for your advise i will have a try.

Comment: @vascowhite I just think that is not enough.

Comment: Why someone think my question is not good and -1 :-(. Tell me and i will correct my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of php validation classes:

http://codecanyon.net/item/easyvalidation-php-special-validation-class/521960

http://taggedzi.com/articles/display/validation-class-for-php

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7120-PHP-Validate-input-values-according-to-many-rules.html

http://www.jasonashdown.co.uk/2008/08/php-validation-class-for-forms/

This one compliments JQuery.

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-validation-php-plugin/

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-validation-php-plugin/ this is great and i will have a try.

Answer (score 2):

If you are already using CodeIgniter, I'd give its form validation another chance.

It actually does pass the form errors back in an array.  You can get it via `validation_errors()` or for more detail `$this->form_validation->_field_data`.  You can extend it with your own validations.  And there are ways to encapsulate it to use outside of CI.

To paraphrase what @ficuscr originally said, you should be working with the framework, not against it.

Comment: CodeIgniter's form validation has most of features i want and if it is easy to be used with CodeIgniter i will do that. Because i will create more restful service and CodeIgniter is not fit for that.